# Implementation status of std::optional in g++/libstdc++?

Tags: c++, g++, libstdc++, option-type, c++14

As I am working on a C++ library that will be released publicly around 2014, I currently have design choices to make. One of the very useful tool that will be released with C++14 is `std::optional`. I would like to know with what version of `g++/libstdc++` I can expect to have it using `-std=c++1y`.

Comment: I changed the tag to C++1y per the Meta discussion linked to on the C++14 tag wiki that resulted in a decision not to use [tag:C++14] until the Final Draft Standard is released.

Comment: if anyone wants to use the reference implementation, it's [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update (Oct 2016):** `std::optional` was not in the final C++14 standard, so it is never available with `-std=c++1y`. Instead GCC 4.9 includes `std::experimental::optional` which is avilable with `-std=c++1y`.

GCC 7 will include `std::optional` with `-std=c++1z` i.e. C++17.

**Original answer (Jun 2013):**

It's currently unimplemented, see http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-06/msg00032.html for the status of C++14 features in GCC's trunk.

When it gets implemented depends on when someone volunteers to do the work, so is impossible to predict.

I would *expect* it will be done for GCC 4.9, which should be released shortly before the C++14 standard, but there are no guarantees.  It is unlikely to get added to GCC 4.8 though, as that's already released and unlike GCC 4.9 (i.e. the GCC subversion trunk) the `__cplusplus` macro has the same value for `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++1y` so for GCC 4.8 there's no way to selectively enable features for `-std=c++1y` only.

Comment: "why ask this on SO" - so people who search for answers on SO find it!

Comment: This was the top google hit when I was investigating why `std::optional` didn't work in gcc ! So I'm glad it was asked and answered here.

Comment: If the question had been asked on the gcc-help list that would have been the top hit. Anyway, this answer was wrong until yesterday, because there was no such thing as `std::optional` until C++17, so it didn't work in any compiler until very recently.

Comment: It simply gets people SO rep. Asking on mailing list won't :p

Answer (score 6):

As per their [libstdc++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) GCC 7.1 is the first version to have `std::optional` without being hidden in `std::experimental` and it supports the `__has_include(<optional>)` feature test. The feature test `__cpp_lib_optional >= 201603` was added in GCC 7.3.